# Typescript overload functions don't autocomplete correctly in IDE

Tags: typescript

I've been trying to make function overloads so my IDE could autocomplete the second paramater's type correctly based on the first argument's value. See example below:

```
class Animal {
    constructor(private name: string) { }

    bark(key: 'said', data: {
        text: string;
    }): void;
    bark(key: 'barked', data: {
        times: number;
    }): void;
    bark(key: 'said' | 'barked', data: any): void {
        if (key === 'said') console.log(`${this.name} said ${data}`);
        if (key === 'barked') for (let i = 0; i < data; i++) console.log('BARK!');
    }
}

const barry = new Animal('Barry');
barry.bark('barked', {
    /* Should auto-complete to { times: number } */
})
```

However the IDE autocompletes to both types for 'barked' and 'said'.
See following example executed on [Typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmE0DeAoavrAHt4IAXAJwFdgSCyAKABzMQDcwSBTaeMZDgLmilm8AOYBKTNAC%20WHHgBGYMgGs6KjgE9BAcghhEAEx0AaaIfZhB2PLeicAHiUHDEYgNzzc08YJYEjT1slVXUtXRCNYzMLEitMLzsSFA4IQXgKZAUOMiC8Hz8AwzzcSLDtaD0DY2gAH0rIjmjzS0EweE1faH8jBLs8RAAzaHLoAF4Jyv0jHUlCYgIQDgA6EAJROgADABIMEgALRAhlnj5pIWroXdiwaU3xErshkY1NccmdRuNJQdoRpZI0EQ42gAAZ3EDoAAeFpxCGIADUCLmRAgixWaw2OgAQrAAEoAaQAhLNHrJZFh5qRoCEyG8xtwOAB3OBIVAgOg45R00lYWmaZZlT7KKKmPp4LA%20LBAA)

[image: Code]

Am I typing it incorrectly? Or perhaps expecting something that is not supported?
Thanks!

Comment: Do your doubt it is about if I use certain param like `cake` the second would need to be `milk`? It is an example

Comment: @VagnerWentz Pretty much, I'm strong typing that function so depending on the first parameter's value (say `cake`), the IDE should know the second parameter expects a type based on `cake` and autocompletes it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question. it seems Typescript is unable to infer the narrowest type (from the first parameter) when working with [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).

One way to achieve what you want is by using Generics. here is how it can be done in your case:

```
type Type1 = {text: string}
type Type2 = {times: number}

class Animal {
    constructor(private name: string) { }

    bark<Key extends "said" | "barked", Data extends (Key extends "said" ? Type1 : Type2)>
    (key: Key, data: Data) : void;
    bark(key: any, data: any): any {
        if (key === 'said') console.log(`${this.name} said ${data}`);
        if (key === 'barked') for (let i = 0; i < data; i++) console.log('BARK!');
    }
} 

    
 const barry = new Animal('Barry');
 barry.bark("barked", {times: 5})
```

Although this works fine in your case, but it's not quite straightforward.